# Reset user password without using "Forgot password?"

Tags: users, 8

I know that in Drupal 7 I could reset the user #1 password via code.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/password.inc';
$newhash = user_hash_password('newpass');
$updatepass = db_update('users') 
  ->fields(array('pass' => $newhash))
  ->condition('uid', '1', '=')
  ->execute();
```

([`user_hash_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) doesn't exist anymore in Drupal 8.)

Alternatively, I could use the following code.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/password.inc';
$edit['pass'] = 'newpass';
$account= user_load(1);
user_save($account, $edit);
```

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8? What API should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easier these days:

```
$account = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(1);
$account->setPassword('new password');
$account->save();
```

Comment: as always very good and clear solution, tnx Master Clive

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, since you seem to be running this as a standalone script, [there is a Drush (9.x) command](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:password/)

```
drush user:password admin mynewpassword
```

For [Drush 8.x and earlier:](http://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-password/):

```
drush user-password admin --password=newpass
```